# cambiar un texto a traves de un formulario con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, formularios

tengo un formulario que el usuario rellena , y esos datos sobreescriben o reemplazan los datos de un elemento con un id; esto es lo que intente , pero no funciona y no se que le falta.
Se supone que el usuario escribe su nombre y deberia cambiarse en el texto.

```
<form action="" name="formulario" method="get">
        <ul>
         <li>
           <label for="usuario">Usuario: </label>
           <input type="text" id="user" name="usuario">
         </li>
          </ul> 
    </form>

<p>Tu</p>
<p id="user">user</p>
<p>, eres nuevo en nuestra plataforma </p>


<button id="cambiar">cambiar</button>

<script>
  
document.getElementById("user")
.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = this.value;
 });


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

No te cambia el texto porque el input y el párrafo tienen el mismo id, los id tienen que ser únicos.

**Solución:**

```js
document.getElementById("userInput").addEventListener("keyup", function(){
        document.getElementById("userParagraph").innerHTML = this.value;
 });
```

```html
<form action="" name="formulario" method="get">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label for="usuario">Usuario: </label>
      <input type="text" id="userInput" name="usuario">
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>

<p>Tu</p>
<p id="userParagraph">user</p>
<p>, eres nuevo en nuestra plataforma </p>


<button id="cambiar">cambiar</button>
```